# Illegal Operation On Bound Member Function C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

So I'm trying to make an event class to mirror C# events. I have seen several implementations that are too involved for what I need. I've come up with the following which fits my purposes:

```
template <typename TFunc>
class Event;

template <class RetType, class... Args>
class Event<RetType(Args...)> final
{
    typedef typename std::function<RetType(Args ...)> Closure;
  public:
    void operator+=(Closure c)
    {
      observers.push_back(c);
    }

    void operator()(Args... args)
    {
        for (auto closure : observers)
            closure(args...);
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Closure> observers;
};
```

This can be used as expected:

```
void Dosomething()
{
    cout << "Did something" << endl;
}
int DosomethingCrazy(int i)
{
    cout << "Did something Crazy " << i << endl;
    return i;
}

int main()
{  
    Event<void()> e1;
    Event<int(int)> e2;
    e1 += Dosomething;
    e2 += DosomethingCrazy;
    e1();
    e2(5);
}
```

But, if I try to subscribe a function within an object I get the error: `'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression` i.e.:

```
class Myclass
{
public:
int num;
Myclass(int i) : num(i) { }
void Dosomething()
{
    cout << "Did something" << num << endl;
}
int DosomethingCrazy(int i)
{
    num = i;
    cout << "Did something Crazy " << num << endl;
    return i;
}
};

int main()
{
Myclass a(0);
Myclass b(10);

Event<int(int)> e1;
Event<int(int)> e2;
e1 += &(a.DosomethingCrazy);  //Error
e2 += &b.DosomethingCrazy;  //Same Error

e1(10);
e2(0);

return 0;
}
```

I have since decided that: even if I were able to accomplish this, it's probably a bad idea to allow external code to subscribe an object's internal methods.

*However*, I am curious what exactly is disallowing this and why. Also,is there a way to accomplish this, and my syntax is just wrong?

NOTE: This could certainly be achieved with static functions and qualifying the function with the class, but I needed to be able to specifically reference the object. As in the example, 'a' and 'b' should end up with swapped integer values.

Comment: `e1 += [&a](int x) { return a.DoSomethingCrazy(x); };`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that produces another compiler error: `binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'main::<lambda_5e.......3e>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` How might I go about adding a lambda?

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/KPKD31619)

Comment: Care to post the code? You just replaced the one line in main right? Whoops, just noticed the link, nvrmnd

Comment: Ahh, of course... I was adding to a void() event, not int(int). Thank you.

Comment: @james member functions cant be called without class' instance, that's why Igor had to capture a and b  by lambda